# WEPopover is not working

Tags: iphone, uitouch

I am using WEPopover in my project.I have integrated it and it's showing PopoverController. The class i added as contentViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController. I am loading another view controller on it's didSelectRowAtIndexPath  but it's not showing this view first time . It appears when i tap it again. I am adding my code. Please help me out from this problem.

Code on UITouch :-

```
if([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[backGroundImageView class]] && numTaps ==1)

    { 

            CGPoint startLocation   = [touch locationInView:backGroundImageView];

             startX = startLocation.x;
             startY = startLocation.y;

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(startX, startY, 300, 90); 



        if(self.popoverController)
        {

            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            self.popoverController = nil;

        }
        else
        {

        UIViewController *contentViewController = [[WEPopoverContentViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];


        self.popoverController = [[[popoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];



        if ([self.popoverController respondsToSelector:@selector(setContainerViewProperties:)]) {
            [self.popoverController setContainerViewProperties:[self improvedContainerViewProperties]];
        }

        self.popoverController.delegate = self;

        //Uncomment the line below to allow the table view to handle events while the popover is displayed.
        //Otherwise the popover is dismissed automatically if a user touches anywhere outside of its view.

        self.popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:backGroundImageView];
        NSLog(@"rect1: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect  
                                                inView:backGroundImageView 
                              permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|
                                                        UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft|UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight)
                                              animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: it's not showing this view first time .It appears when i tap it again.That means WEPopover controller is not showing first time right ?

Comment: No WEPopover is showing but yes it's not loading the viewController first time. If you know then please tell me the solution

Answer (score 1):

In `else` part try with this little change, may be helpful As I have used like this way and it works fine.

```
self.popoverController = [[[WEPopoverContentViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourAnotherViewController] autorelease];
```

Assuming that self.popoverController is object of WEPopoverContentViewController
Assuming that yourAnotherViewController is allocated